# Can't validate because returned content in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm trying to validate input with jQuery, here's what that looks like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var name = $("#name1").val();
    var url = $("#url").val();
    var success = $("#success").val();
    var fail = $("#failure").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();

    $("#name1").on('keyup', function(){
        var name = $("#name1").val();
        console.log(name);
    });
    $("#url").on('keyup', function(){
        var url = $("#url").val();
        console.log(url);
    });

    $("#success").on('keyup', function(){
        var success = $("#success").val();
        console.log(success);   
    })
    $("#failure").on('keyup', function(){
        var fail = $("#failure").val();
        console.log(fail);
            if(success == fail){
        console.log(true);
    }
    })
    $("#email").on('keyup', function(){
        var email = $("#email").val();
        console.log(email);
    })

});
```

Now say I wanted to check if the name and email are the same, how would I? Whenever I do all that happens is it get processed when the page loads. Any help?

Comment: "*Now say I wanted to check if the name and email are the same*". When do you want to do that? While submitting the form?

Comment: Well as the user types. @Oriol

Comment: As the user types, would I just add the check in the keyup function? I can't access the variable if I do @CyrilDD

Comment: How would I access the other variable though? @CyrilDD

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to check if they're the same as they user types. You could do something like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var name = $("#name1").val();
    var url = $("#url").val();
    var success = $("#success").val();
    var fail = $("#failure").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();

    $("#name1").on('keyup', function(){
        var name = $("#name1").val();
        console.log(name);
        checkEmailAndName();
    });
    $("#url").on('keyup', function(){
        var url = $("#url").val();
        console.log(url);
    });

    $("#success").on('keyup', function(){
        var success = $("#success").val();
        console.log(success);   
    })
    $("#failure").on('keyup', function(){
        var fail = $("#failure").val();
        console.log(fail);
            if(success == fail){
        console.log(true);
    }
    })
    $("#email").on('keyup', function(){
        var email = $("#email").val();
        console.log(email);
        checkEmailAndName();
    })

});

function checkEmailAndName()
{
    if($("#email").val() == $("#name1").val())
    {
        //Handle if they are the same
    }
    else
    {
        //Handle if they are different
    }
}
```